# undefined symbol : crt__itow_s

Tags: function, assembly, masm32, msvcrt

I got a piece of code:

```
            push    0Ah             ; Radix
            push    2               ; fSizeInWords
            lea     eax, [ebp+DstBuf]
            and     dword ptr [ebp+DstBuf], 0
            push    eax             ; DstBuf
            push    7
            pop     ecx
            xor     edx, edx
            mov     eax, ebx
            div     ecx
            push    edx             ; Val
            call    _itow_s
```

After change _itow_s to crt__itow_s, I got error reported:undefined symbol : crt__itow_s.
Does _itow_s in msvcrt.lib ? How to pass the _itow_s function in masm32.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to change `_itow_s` to `crt__itow_s`?

Comment: Since wtoi and itow is in msvcrt library, I thought this function should be the same。

Answer (score 0):

I changed to the LoadLibrary method

```
                
LibName       db "ntdll.dll",0
ProcName      db "_itow_s",0

                ...
                push    0Ah             ; Radix
                push    2               ; fSizeInWords
                lea     eax, [ebp+DstBuf]
                and     dword ptr [ebp+DstBuf], 0
                push    eax             ; DstBuf
                push    7
                pop     ecx
                xor     edx, edx
                mov     eax, ebx
                div     ecx
                push    edx             ; Val
                ;call    _itow_s
                invoke LoadLibrary,ADDR LibName
                invoke GetProcAddress,eax,ADDR ProcName
                call    eax
```